# inject context HttpServletRequest cause "interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader" (jersey 2.21, weblogic 12.1.3)

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

I am using jersey 2.21 on weblogic 12c (12.1.3) to provide Rest. The Rest class is working fine without injecting context HTTPServeletRequest/HTTPServletResponse. But once inject the context, it throws "interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader" error, when calling the service.

Here is the class:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestResource.class);


@Context HttpServletResponse resp; 
@Context HttpServletRequest request; 


/**
 * Test site connectivity. Return parameter txt's content in reply
 * @param content
 * @return 
 */
@GET
@Path("/tryMe")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String echoTest(@QueryParam("txt") String content) { 
    System.out.println("Try me reach.");
    System.out.println("from client: "+request.getRemoteAddr()); 


    return content;
}

}
```

If comment out those two contexts, no error when calling tryMe Restful.
 
When using thwo two contexts, calling tryMe restful, will throw following errors:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
        A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
        1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader
        2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to create a Proxy for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest in scope org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped an error occured while creating the proxy

            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ProxyUtilities.generateProxy(ProxyUtilities.java:225)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2044)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
            at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.ContextInjectionResolver.resolve(ContextInjectionResolver.java:126)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
        Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:581)
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)
            at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)
            at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

here is the weblogic.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:context-root>demoRest</wls:context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <!-- slf4j -->
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>

        <!-- jersey-bundle-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- Jackson-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- jsr311*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- javassist -->
        <wls:package-name>javassist.*</wls:package-name>
        <!-- aop repackaged -->
        <wls:package-name>org.aopalliance.*</wls:package-name>


        <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.internal.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.tiger_types.*</wls:package-name>


        <!-- jpa2.1 hibernate -->
        <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- commons io <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.io.*</wls:package-name> -->
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>


    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- jersey -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>jersey.repackaged.*</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- hk2 -->
        <wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- slf4j -->
        <wls:resource-name>org.slf4j</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- jersey-bundle-*.jar -->
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- Jackson-*.jar -->
        <wls:resource-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- jsr311*.jar -->
        <wls:resource-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- jpa2.1 hibernate -->
        <wls:resource-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>javax.validation.*</wls:resource-name>

        <!-- commons io -->
        <wls:resource-name>org.apache.commons.io.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to resolve this exception?

Comment: Has a solution been found for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot inject HttpServletRequest in ContainerRequestFilter via @Context jersey2.x and weblogic 12.1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400142/cannot-inject-httpservletrequest-in-containerrequestfilter-via-context-jersey2)

Comment: It'a Jersey bug and it's still open: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3422

Answer (score 1):

check [duplicate topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400142/cannot-inject-httpservletrequest-in-containerrequestfilter-via-context-jersey2/39884183#39884183), you can use static access if you absolutely have to

```
HttpServletRequest request= 
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem and found workaround: I move injection of request to method declaration and that's work for me:

```
    @GET
    public void test(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This solution isn't enough to solve the problem of injection.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there seemed to be some issue with making it a Component, so I had to remove the annotation @Component. The error then disappeared. I see there were some issues mentioned here in glassfish:[Glassfish issue](https://java.net/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/GLASSFISH-20885/GLASSFISH-20885.html)

However I'm not sure if these have been fixed or are related to Jersey. If you can do without @Component then that is probably the best solution as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem when deploying rest project in weblogic 12c, as jediz suggested try with that solution. Additionally you have to add listener in web.xml.

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Comment: @Mohammad Abdullah., after adding this also the problem exists.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 4
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.glassfish.hk2.api.ProxyCtl is not visible from class loader

Comment: @Madhesh , Before deploying Restful web services application, v have to register web services in weblogic . Please follow this [link.](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/RESTF/use-jersey20-ri.htm#RESTF290) Once this war deployed, then restart the managed web server and deploy the web services application.